# WatchKit: What is "Kermit" and what does this console log statement mean?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm exploring the WatchKit SDK, and I keep seeing this error statement in my console log as I navigate the app in the simulator:

```
2014-11-20 10:43:11.154 MyWatchApp WatchKit Extension[32002:1257966] Can't append data to log file, even after retrying. Giving up. Facilities: <CFArray 0x7fa9d84048d0 [0x110325ef0]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
0 : <CFString 0x10ff04c48 [0x110325ef0]>{contents = "Kermit"}
)}
```

What's going on here? What is Kermit? How can I capture and explore this warning?

Comment: `log(UIColor.greenColor())` - **Error: It's not easy being green**

Comment: There's this [post](https://devforums.apple.com/click.jspa?searchID=7054022&objectType=2&objectID=1074980) on Apple's Developer Forum that may have something to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem for following situation:
I had Interface Controller in Storyboard, but Class for it was not set.

When I made new class from WKInterfaceController and set it in Storyboard, problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In addition to WebOrCode's tip to make sure the Class of your Interface Controller in your Storyboard is set properly, you also need to make sure that the class file itself has the right Target set.  When you created the file, you may have accidentally set the Target for the main iPhone app. The Target should be the WatchKit Extension.  View the file in the File Inspector and look for the section that says "Target Membership". Make sure your WatchKit Extension is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the file, and make sure you have the WatchKit Extension group/folder selected when you do. This will include the file in the necessary target.

[image]